# Wordpress : month between 2 dates

Tags: wordpress, date, custom-post-type

I would like to retrieve posts based on the current month.
My customs post type has a **start date** and an **end date.**

If the current month is between this period, then retrieve the items.

Someone can help me ?

```html
$date_month = (new DateTime)->format('m');
      $start = get_field('start_date');
      $end = get_field('start_end');

      // parameters of $upcoming
      $args_upcoming_period = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'post_type' => array('sports', 'culture'),

       'meta_query' => array(
          array(
            'key' =>  $date_month,
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'value' => array($start, $end),
          )
        ),
      );
      $upcoming_period = new WP_Query($args_upcoming_period);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code:

```
$start_date = "here_value"; //e.g. 2019-01-01
$end_date = "here_value"; //e.g. 2019-02-01
$metaKey = "here_value"; //e.g. date

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => $metaKey,
            'value' => array($start_date, $end_date),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
    )
);

$result = new WP_Query($args);
```

Please note, var `start_date` & `end_date` they must be in the sql format (e.g. YYYY-MM-DD).
And meta_key compile with field you want filter. (e.g. `date`)